# What are some of the examples of non-linear uniform accelaration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

Are there any cases where the acceleration is uniform but it's not along a straight line? If yes, please explain them.

Comment: Do you mean acceleration whose magnitude constant but not along one direction?

Comment: No, that would be in case of uniform circular motion. Actually there's a statement in my book: **"If a particle is moving with uniform acceleration, this does not necessarily imply that it's moving along a straight line"**. This means there must be some example(s) of uniform acceleration which is/are non-linear. Else this statement is wrong. Now if magnitude is constant and not direction in acceleration, then according to the definition of uniform acceleration, it can't be uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is very correct.

It is velocity and not acceleration that tells us that how a body is moving.

Suppose you throw a ball horizontally from a height. It follows a parabolic path till it strikes the ground. All this time the only force acting on it is the gravity and it moves with a constant acceleration $g$ that continuously acts downwards.

**Edit:**
I guess you misinterpreted the statement of the book. The book states that if a body has constant acceleration(both in direction and magnitude), then it is not necessary that it('the body') is moving in straight line.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was confusing myself with this particular example. I was misinterpreting the direction of body i.e the parabolic path with the direction of acceleration which is in fact constantly acting downwards.